# Homogeneity of the space of semicontinuous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

I am interested in the topological homogeneity of function spaces.

Question. Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space, let $USC(X)$ be a space of upper semicontinuous functions on $X$ and let $USC(X)^+$ be a space of non-negative upper semicontinuous functions on $X$.

1. Is the space $USC(X)$ topologically homogeneous ?
2. Is the space $USC(X)^+$ topologically homogeneous ?
3. What about $USC(X,[0,1])$ ?

Comment: topology of pointwise convergence

Comment: I think that for a countable Tychonoff space containing a non-trivial convergent sequence it is possible to prove that all three spaces are absorbing and hence topologically homogeneous.  Is such answer satisfactory for your purposes?

Comment: The question can be narrowed down to perfectly normal spaces $X$  with a countable injective weight.

Comment: What about metrizable compact spaces $X$?

Comment: Taras, even for a metrizable compact, I do not know the answer. But great interest for perfectly normal spaces with a countable i-weight of power is no more than a continuum.